# How do we see a query plan executed by Google Cloud BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How do we display the query plan executed by Google Cloud BigQuery if it is available?

Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore Execution details tab of the Query results. The tab explains query plan besides including some additional information like query execution time, slots consumed etc.

For more details you can refer https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation?hl=en_US&_ga=2.267980487.-856640327.1563816458.